# Download jars from nexus using ant build tool as done automatically in Maven

Tags: ant, maven, jar, download, nexus

I have a build.xml(ant based) which requires some jar from nexus to get copied in existing lib folder. i.e when it builds it should copy the jar from nexus with some version defined & then copy in lib & do compilation.
like happen in  maven we define the artifact & its version . If changed will automatically download it from maven repo.
how can i do this in ant based builds?

experts pls advice.

Comment: Take a detailed look at Ivy which can directly use Maven Repositories. http://ant.apache.org/ivy/

Answer (score 8):

I have taken the example listed in this thread one step further and created a macrodef to clean things up a bit for re-use. See below for downloading two artifacts from nexus (one snapshot, one release).

```
<project>
<target name="get-all">
    <mkdir dir="lib" />
    <nexus-get 
        groupId="foo.bar" 
        artifactId="some-artifact"
        version="1.0.28"
        repo="releases"
        extension="jar" 
        dest="lib" 
    />

    <nexus-get 
        groupId="foo.bar" 
        artifactId="another-artifact"
        version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
        repo="snapshots"
        extension="jar" 
        dest="lib" 
    />
</target>

<macrodef name="nexus-get">
    <attribute name="groupId"/>
    <attribute name="artifactId"/>
    <attribute name="version"/>
    <attribute name="repo"/>
    <attribute name="extension"/>
    <attribute name="dest"/>

    <sequential>
        <get src="http://my-nexus:9999/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=@{repo}&amp;g=@{groupId}&amp;a=@{artifactId}&amp;v=@{version}&amp;e=@{extension}" dest="@{dest}/@{artifactId}.@{extension}" usetimestamp="true" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Nexus redirects with 307 which is not supported until ant 1.9, so be sure to upgrade.

Comment: @Lance Java How do you login when your sonatype nexus needs authorization. I've the username and password stored in a properties file in user home directory.

Comment: BTW, this is an excellent macro if the repository is public. Needs extension to add authorizaiton.

Comment: I'm guessing the nexus rest api supports http authentication so you can probably specify a username/password on the ant [get task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html). You could also look at the nexus rest api documentation, perhaps you need to hit [this](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/path__authentication_login.html) first?

Answer (score 4):

You would probably be interested in [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/index.html). It is a sub-project of Ant for dependency management. It is perfect for your situation because it can read Maven repositories and provides Ant tasks for downloading the published artifacts, constructing class paths from them, etc.  It supports your use case of getting the most recent version of a dependency if you configure it to ask for the "latest.release" revision of the module.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are surely specific ways to combine ant and maven the simplest thing (if you know the nexus URL and your artifact parameters to construct the download URL) would be just to use the ant [Get](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) task.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="resolveDependencies" basedir=".">
  <target name="resolveDependencies">
   <mkdir dir="lib" />
   <get src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/log4j/1.2.9/log4j-1.2.9.jar" dest="lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar" usetimestamp="true" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/).

As shown on http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html
Can list dependencies in ant, and also do things like copy them

I think the section **Using FileSets and the Version Mapper** covers your need

You can use is filesetId, which will give you a fileset reference that can be used to copy files into a particular location. For example, to populate WEB-INF/lib with your dependencies you could use the following:

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
  <dependency groupId="junit" artifactId="junit" version="3.8.2" scope="test"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
<copy todir="${webapp.output}/WEB-INF/lib">
  <fileset refid="dependency.fileset" />
  <!-- This mapper strips off all leading directory information -->
  <mapper type="flatten" />
</copy>
```